# How to setup multiple cakephp projects with 1 app folder?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I would like to run multiple projects frontends in the same webroot with 1 app production folder as per below:

cake/ 
app/
controllers/
webroot/ 
--project_1/index.php
--project_2/index.php

I am doing this so that i can manage version control using the same admin panel. And when i need to deploy each site i will upload the latest app and webroot folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different folder for different frontend like below folder structure for Cakephp 2.2.4

```
app
---->Config
---->Controller
---->Model
---->Views
---->webroot
---->.htaccess
---->index.php
admin
---->Config
---->Controller
---->Model
---->Views
---->webroot
---->.htaccess
---->index.php
lib
plugins
vendors
.gitignore
.htaccess
index.php
```

Means you have to copy **app** folder multiple times for setup multiple frontend. setup database same, so you can use **admin** folder as admin and other app1,app2 folders as frontend.